# Api not working after nodejs updated to version 18

Tags: node.js, sharepoint, nestjs, pnp-js

We recently updated runtime nodejs 18 after that one api got failed and return 500 internal server error.

Also thrown this error in server

```
TypeError: Failed to parse URL from
at .Request ( node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5272 )
at .mergeHeaders ( /layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_modules/node_modules/@pnp/common-commonjs/net.js:9 )
at .SPHttpClient.<anonymous> ( /layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_modules/node_modules/@pnp/sp-commonjs/sphttpclient.js:38 )
at .step ( /layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_modules/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143 )
at .Object.next ( /layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_modules/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124 )
```

We are calling API to fetch sharepoint folder structure because of this structure not loaded in UI and get failed

But not sure where exactly Api get failed and what to do to get rid of this.